# SCOM 2012 - SQL Server Monitoring

Tags: sql-server-2005, scom

I have been tasked to see whether `SCOM 2012` is the right tool to do the following, which have been asked of me:

- Find out what  are the longest running queries
- Find out the number of locks

Does anyone have any advice, or can anyone point me to a comprehensive guide in trying to get `SCOM` to monitor the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SCOM` is extended using management packs. [The Microsoft SQL Server management pack is documented here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd767418.aspx).

If you look at the `Appendix - Reports` section you'll see that out-of-the-box reports include `SQL Server Lock Analysis` and `Top 5 Deadlocked Databases`.

The management pack does alert on long running SQL Agent *jobs*, but it does not monitor or report on long running queries. For that, you may need to look at some more SQL-specific analysis tools or use SQL scripts (such as this one: [Find the TOP n Longest Running Procedures (or Queries), Ordered by Total Impact on Server](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=LongRunningProcs&referringTitle=Home))

Answer (score 0):

You can also get quite extensive information on what each management pack contains by visiting MPWiki. [The SQL management pack is detailed here](http://mpwiki.viacode.com/default.aspx?g=posts&t=101470).